# JSON value parse with Python

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON bits like this below and I need to access only the datetime field from the values instead of the first integer entry but I cannot find a way to do that using Python. Any ideas?

```
{
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "values": [
    [
      "95", 
      "2011-12-04"
    ], 
    [
        "90", 
        "2011-10-03"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack the values in a loop:

```
import json

data = json.loads(your_json_value)

for _, date in data['values']:
    # do something with `date`
```

I assigned the first value in each nested list to `_`, a variable traditionally used to tell the code reader that you are ignoring that value.

If you wanted to do anything useful with the date, you may want to parse it:

```
import json
import datetime

data = json.loads(your_json_value)

for _, date in data['values']:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> import datetime
>>> your_json_value = '''\
... {
...   "boolean": true,
...   "null": null,
...   "number": 123,
...   "values": [
...     [
...       "95", 
...       "2011-12-04"
...     ], 
...     [
...         "90", 
...         "2011-10-03"
...     ]
...   ]
... }
... '''
>>> for _, date in data['values']:
...     date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
...     print('{:%a %d %B %Y}'.format(date))
... 
Sun 04 December 2011
Mon 03 October 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

after turning it into a python dict:

```
for data_list in your_dict['values']:
  # ['95', '2011-12-04']
  date_str = data_list[1]
```